# How to subtract the value from the given reference from the other excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Sheet 1

[[image: 1]]

values of 1 2 under the heading 'A' 'B' are given in the 
Sheet 2

[image]

under heading 'y'

I want to find value of 'X' using formula 1-2 whose value are given in the 
Sheet 2

As you can see values are 1=0, 2=0, 3=175, 4=175, 5=258 and so on 
Under the Sheet 1 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IHSK.jpg) to calculate under 
heading X

cell 1 is 2-1 values are 0-0 so result would be =0

cell 1 is 5-2 values are 258-0 so result would be =258

cell 2 is 4-3 values are 175-175 so result would be =0

cell 3 is 8-5 values are 341.5-258.25 so result would be =83.25

How would I do that using the formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX` and `MATCH`:

`VLOOKUP`:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,F:H,3,0)-VLOOKUP(B2,F:H,3,0)
```

[image]

`INDEX`/`MATCH` (longer but more robust to column additions and such):

```
=INDEX(H:H,MATCH(C2,F:F,0))-INDEX(H:H,MATCH(B2,F:F,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Cheers Mate